# How to export to $PATH permanently because .bashrc file doesn't exist in $HOME directory

Tags: bash, path

I am trying to figure out macOS and want to install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) which was not a problem....but I need the Laravel and Symfony installer and in the documentation it says that I need to export the variable in .bashrc file.

Normally that file is in /home/username/ directory on Linux

But where is the .bashrc file on the Mac? How to export to the PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be stored in `/Users/username/`. To append something to your `.bashrc` file use

```
echo foo >> ~/.bashrc
```

Make sure to use `>>` and not `>`, as the latter will overwrite the file.

As @fd0 said, you probably want this in your `.bash_profile` to make sure it loads. I would append to your `.bash_profile` like this:

```
echo "export PATH="$HOME/path/added:$PATH"" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: But it is not there. And if I create one and write export PATH there it doesn't have any effect

Comment: You do not need to use `sudo` to write to your own `.bashrc`.

Comment: you can use `touch ~/.bashrc` to create the bashrc file if it doesn't exist. You'll have to use `$PATH` to reference the correct variable, not just PATH.

Comment: The terminal emulator starts the shell as a login shell. `.bashrc` will not be read. Use either `.bash_login`, `.bash_profile`, or `.profile`.

Comment: where is that .bash_profile file???

Comment: @lewis4u in the same directory as `~/.bashrc`, in `/Users/username/`. If it doesn't exist you can create it with `touch ~/.bash_profile`